# Solution of differential equation using other differential equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have a differential equation $y'(t)+2a\sqrt{e+y(t)+1}=h-2a$ where $e,h$ and $a$ are constants with the terminal condition $y(T)=0$; $T$ may be 10 or 12... etc.

And $x'(t)+(a/\sqrt{e+y(t)+1}) x(t)=-d$ where $d$ is constant With initial condition 
$x(0)=10$ or 12 etc . I have to plot $x$ with respect to $t$.
I have tried to solve the equation so far with

```
DSolve[{y'[x] == h + 2*a*(Sqrt (e + y[x] + 1) - 1), y[10] == 0}, y[x], x]
```

Comment: e == 1.2; h == 1; a == 0.2; d == 2;
DSolve[{y'[t] + 2 Sqrt[e + y[t] + 1] == h - 2 a, y[10] == 0, 
  x'[t] + a/Sqrt[e + y[t] + 1] x[t] == -d, x[0] == 10}, {x, y}, t]        if i sove this it showing Running for long period of time. Is there any probem in this program?

Answer (score 4):

When you type

```
e == 1.2; h == 1; a == 0.2; d == 2;
```

you aren't really setting the variable `e` equal to 1.2, what you are doing is making a statement that can either be true or false.  Type `3 == 4` and see the response, then try `3=4`.  The first gives the answer `False` the second gives an error.  See the pages for [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) and [`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html).

So if you try

```
e = 1.2; h = 1; a = 0.2; d = 2;

sol = DSolve[{y'[t] + 2 Sqrt[e + y[t] + 1] == h - 2 a,
   y[10] == 0,
   x'[t] + a/Sqrt[e + y[t] + 1] x[t] == -d,
   x[0] == 10}, {x, y}, {t, -10, 10}]
```

You get the error

> During evaluation of In[203]:= Solve::inex: Solve was unable to solve
>   the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct
>   rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many
>   of the methods used by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with
>   an exact version of the system may help. >>

This means that the numbers 1.2 and 0.2 aren't exact (they are floating point approximations to numbers).  You can make the change

```
e = 6/5; h = 1; a = 1/5; d = 2;
```

and try again, but now you get the error

> DSolve::bvnul: For some branches of the general solution, the given
>   boundary conditions lead to an empty solution. >>

Why is this?  Maybe someone else can chime in.  But I do know that you can solve it numerically using `NDSolve`, you just won't get an analytic answer.  There is a bit of a difference with `NDSolve` in that you have to specify the range over which you want to have a solution.  Here I'll set it to $t=\pm20$

```
e = 6/5; h = 1; a = 1/5; d = 2;

sol = NDSolve[{y'[t] + 2 Sqrt[e + y[t] + 1] == h - 2 a,
   y[10] == 0,
   x'[t] + a/Sqrt[e + y[t] + 1] x[t] == -d,
   x[0] == 10}, {x, y}, {t, -20, 20}]
```

[image]

Now you can plot the answer via

```
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 20}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image]

Comment: e = 6/5; h = 1; a = 1/5; d = 2;

sol = NDSolve[{y'[t] + 2 Sqrt[e + y[t] + 1] == h - 2 a, y[10] == 0, 
   x'[t] + a/Sqrt[e + y[t] + 1] x[t] == -d, x[0] == 10}, {x, 
   y}, {t, -20, 20}]

Comment: NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 10000 steps reached at the point t == 0.0000803814074775227`. >>

Comment: {{x -> \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"InterpolatingFunction", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "20.`"}], ",", "0.0000803814074775227`"}], "}"}], "}"}], 
        ",", "\"\<<>\>\""}], "]"}],
False,
Editable->False]\), y -> \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"InterpolatingFunction", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "20.`"}], ",", "0.0000803814074775227`"}], "}"}], "}"}], 
        ",", "\"\<<>\>\""}], "]"}],
False,
Editable->False]\)}}
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 20}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"x", "y"}]

Comment: {{x -> \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"InterpolatingFunction", "[", "]"}],
False,
Editable->False]\), y -> \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"InterpolatingFunction", "[", "]"}],
False,
Editable->False]\)}}

Comment: InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {0.000408571} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used. >>

Comment: InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {0.000408571} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used. >>

Comment: the graph is not comming

Comment: please help me to get it

Comment: i try but .graph is blank

Comment: NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 10000 steps reached at the point t == 0.0000803814074775227`. >>

Comment: InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {0.000408571} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used. >>

Comment: please tell me what will be the value of x and y

Comment: What I wrote above works, so I don't know why it isn't work for you.  Please open a new notebook, only type in the above, quit the kernel, and enter that stuff.  Then take a screenshot, maybe I can spot an error that way.

Comment: how can i add this screenshot here?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ewop6kW.png?1

Comment: now see and tell me